# How to make a grid item stretch to full width if next element is hidden?

Tags: css, css-grid

guys. I'm trying to understand CSS Grid and found a behaviour I thought would be simple but turned out to be a little complicated.
I need to follow a 12-column layout a have a row with 2 elements but I need these elements to fill 100% of the width if it is the single element.

I tried to use auto-fit and it almost did the job but I couldn't find a way to explicitly set 12 columns this way.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```html
<div class="autofit">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="banner"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.autofit { 
            display:grid; 
            grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
            grid-gap: 20px;
            text-align: center; 
    } 

   .autofit .content{  
            grid-column: 1/9;
   }
   .autofit .banner { 
            grid-column: 10/-1; 
    }
```

This way the grid works as expected but if I delete the .banner element the .content doesn't stretch to fill the available space ):

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `:only-child` to define and extra rule:

```css
.autofit {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin:5px;
}
.autofit > *{
  height:20px;
}
.autofit .content {
  grid-column: 1/9;
  background:red;
}

.autofit .banner {
  grid-column: 10/-1;
  background:blue;
}

.autofit > :only-child{
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="autofit">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="banner"></div>
</div>

<div class="autofit">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>

<div class="autofit">
  <div class="banner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You try this.

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
}
.grid-container--fit {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}
.grid-container div{background:#ff0000;}
```

```html
<div class="autofit grid-container grid-container--fit">
  <div class="content">test</div>
  <div class="banner">test</div>
</div>
Auto fit
<div class="autofit grid-container grid-container--fit">
  <div class="content">test</div>
</div>
```